# Insert html using jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jquery-selectors

I want to insert a large chunk of html into a pre-existing `<td>`.  I am using this method:

```
 $("td#content").html(LOTS_OF_HTML_CODE_HERE);
```

But it doesn't work. I am a noob, there are a lot of quotes and `'` within the HTML chunk that seems to be breaking it.  What is the correct method for doing this?

Comment: Please show the exact code of your `html()` command and the HTML you're injecting it in.

Comment: where is your html ? May be sometime wrong in html data and need to check.

Comment: Where are your LOTS_OF_HTML_CODE coming from? Maybe you could escape it with your server side script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest unifying the html into one string... like so.

```
htmlStr = "";
htmlStr += "<p>some paragraph";
htmlStr += "<p>another paragaraph</p>";

$("#content").html(htmlStr);
```

this way you can see where your html is breaking down and it adds a lot of readability to javascript created content.

Also...

if there is content in this TD that you'd like to keep, I would use the `append()` jquery method.

---

the [jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) is your best friend!

Answer (score 8):

Javascript doesn't have good support for multi-line strings or HEREDOC syntax, but there are a few workarounds.

Add a backslash "\" to the end of each line to let the script engine know you are continuing onto the next line without finishing:

```
<script>
var my_html = '\
    <div id="my-div">\
        <span>Name:</span> Your Name\
    </div>\
';
</script>
```

Use an XML CDATA hack(http://mook.wordpress.com/2005/10/30/multi-line-strings-in-javascript/):

```
<script>
var my_html = (<r><![CDATA[

    <div id="my-div">
        <span>Name:</span>Your Name
    </div>

]]></r>).toString();
</script>
```

Comment: they added a feature to allow this easily now.  You can store text in newlines now if you surround it with ` instead of a single-quote.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to put all of that HTML into a div as per: `<div id="myHTML" style="display: none;">LOTS OF HTML HERE</div>` then when do this:

```
$("td#content").html($("#myHTML").html());
```

*What could be the problem is line breaks. If you have a string (enclosed in "" or '') then you will find that line breaks will "break" your code... so you'll have to put all the HTML on one line.*

Answer (score 1):

Stefan is right, but to answer your question with quotes, don't forget to escape anything that would otherwise break it, so if you have `html("<a href='#' onclick='dofunction("text")'>...etc...");` it needs to be `html("<a href='#' onclick='dofunction(\"text\")'>...etc...");` in order for the double quotes to not be read literally.

Answer (score 1):

If quotes are breaking your code, try this...

`$("td#content").html("<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">my link</a>");`

The quotes are not being escaped. Just add a backslash before any quotes, double or single within your HTML code. That should do it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it's coming in from a link, you'll probably want to do it with AJAX:

```
$("#YOUR_ELEMENT").load("THE_CONTENT_TO_LOAD");
```

However, keep in mind if you're trying to pull HTML from a site on a different domain you'll need to use server proxies and all that stuff...kind of out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be creating your elements with jquery, rather than in a big string. You get no certainty of dom correctness if you just use a big string, and it's near impossible to debug or modify.

This is similar to building xml by hand. It's just not the preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the grave accent ( ` ), like that:

```
$("#menu").html(`
    
Options:
<a href="main.html">Home</a> | 
<a href="list.html">List</a> |
Add |
Options |
<a href=# id="logout">Logout</a>
         
`);
```