# Printing html from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Just looking for some assistance. I have html tags in JSON. But when i try to print it, the tags simply print as string and are not being interpreted as HTML. e.g  <\bold> or <\br>

When using PHP i would decode it and then it would print as expected. How do i go about doing this so i can append it to an element via jquery?

Example code

```
response = { 
  "title": "<bold>This is the title</bold><br>Next is the body<br>" 
};
$('#title').text(response.title);
```

Thanks

Comment: `text()` outputs just that. Use `html()` instead

Comment: `.html()` instead of `.text()`. But be aware of the content! `<script>` tags will also be executed upon insertion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert html using jquery .html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479783/insert-html-using-jquery-html)

Comment: Cheers guys. So simple... I thought i had to do some decoding.

Comment: You need to know that the HTML you mention in your text is invalid. There is no such thing as `<bold></bold>` or `</br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.html()` function istead of `.text()`.

```js
response = { 
  "title": "<bold>This is the title</bold><br>Next is the body<br>" 
};
$('#title').html(response.title);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title"></div>
```